# OpenSSL code woes

Tags: c, openssl, ssl-certificate

So I'm writing some C code to connect to a server that is expecting me to provide a certificate for authentication.  I'm using OpenSSL to do the SSL communications and I've got the socket code worked out, and I have code to do the SSL part worked out to, but what I can't seem to get simply because the docs are so sparse is how to implement the function:
SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb

If any one has any tips I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you created the context for the X509 cert and EVP_key? Please paste the code to get more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb()`.  The simplest way is to use `SSL_use_certificate_file()` to set the certificate and `SSL_use_PrivateKey_file()` to set the corresponding private key, *before* calling `SSL_connect()`.